Is there a ggplot geom to fill between two paths, not lines?
I have cyclic data that I am trying to plot a mean overlaid on a standard deviation band. Using geom_ribbon() has the same issue as geom_line() as it connects the nearest x values, not the order of the data. Is there a way to fill data between two paths, not lines?
Here is an example. As the resulting figure shows the standard deviation lines from geom_ribbon() are connected by nearest x whereas geom_path() correctly plots the lines. The desired graphic should fill the area between the red and blue standard deviation lines.
library(tidyverse)

DF <- tibble(
  Order = seq(1,20),
  x = c(seq(0,18,2), seq(19, 1, -2)),
  y = sin(4.5*(Order-1)*pi/180),
  sd1 = y + 1,
  sd2 = y - 1
)

p <- ggplot(DF, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = sd1, ymax = sd2), fill = 'lightblue', alpha = 0.2) +
  geom_path() +
  geom_path(aes(y=sd1), col = 'blue') +
  geom_path(aes(y=sd2), col = 'red')
    
ggsave('plot.png', p)



Please provide some description or image that represents your expected output.

Updated the question, hopefully more clear what I am aiming for.

Yo've said "area" singular.   Do you mean the area between the upper blue line and the lower red line should be filled?  Or the area between the two blue lines should be filled and, separately, the area between the two red lines?  Or something else? It might be clearer if you gave us two plots: one with the black(?) path correctly plotted and one with the ribbon(s) correctly plotted.

No generalizable answer there so not suggesting a close, but related to this question.

Thanks. Definitely looking for a generalizable approach as real data has varied number of cycles and each cycle has variable number of points. Thinking of using a grouping variable and geom_path to just draw vertical lines between matched points of upper and lower standard deviations. Not really the shading I want but ...

Isn't that what geom_polygon() does? Just like geom_path, it connects the observations in the order in which they appear in the data.

Yes, thanks. Requires some significant wrangling but this will do the trick.

library(tidyverse)
library(zoo)

DF <- tibble(
  Order = seq(1,20),
  x = c(seq(0,18,2), seq(19, 1, -2)),
  y = sin(4.5*(Order-1)*pi/180),
  sd1 = y + 1,
  sd2 = y - 1
)

DF %>% 
  mutate(sl1 = (sd1 - lag(sd1, default = first(sd1))) / (x - lag(x, default = 1)),
         sl2 = (sd2 - lag(sd2, default = first(sd2))) / (x - lag(x, default = 1))) %>% 
  {full_join(filter(., sl1 < 0) %>% select(-sd2, -sl1, -sl2),
             filter(., sl2 >= 0) %>% select(-sd1, -sl1, -sl2))} %>% 
  arrange(x) %>% 
  mutate(sd1_app = zoo::na.spline(sd1, na.rm = F),
         sd2_app = zoo::na.spline(sd2, na.rm = F)) -> DF1

ggplot(DF, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
  geom_ribbon(data = DF1, aes(ymin = sd1_app, ymax = sd2_app), 
              fill = 'lightblue', alpha = 0.3) +
  geom_path() +
  geom_path(aes(y=sd1), col = 'blue') +
  geom_path(aes(y=sd2), col = 'red')


Created on 2024-06-25 with reprex v2.0.2
